# Find all messages that have been enqueued in Service Bus subscription for longer than 10 seconds

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

I have a requirement to **peek** at all the messages on a specific topic subscription and check if any have been enqueued for more than 10 seconds.

I do not have manage access

There seem to be different approaches possible

```
 private async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
 {
    var timeEnqueued = message.SystemProperties.EnqueuedTimeUtc;
    var duration = (DateTime.UtcNow - timeEnqueued).TotalSeconds;

    if (duration > 10)
    {
        _messages.Add(message);
    }
}

var subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(_configurationProvider.TopicListen, StaticSettings.TopicName, subscriptionName);

var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
{
    MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
    AutoComplete = false,
    MaxAutoRenewDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
};

_messages.Clear();

subscriptionClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
var body = $"{_messages.Count} found in Service Bus Subscription.  Please check";
```

The logic above will not work because the messages are read off a separate thread

How do I wait until the messages have all been read?

Is there an easier way to do this?

I wanted to use the PeekBatch approach but my subscription client doesn't have this method?

Any ideas?

Cheers

Paul

Comment: You have to `await` inside the `ProcessMessagesAsync` method and see if the `subscriptionClient` can wait for the results.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is set the Time to Live for a message with this 10 seconds. After that they will get expired, but you enable them to be moved to the dead letter queue.

(EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration)

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-expiration

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues